# vba locking / unlocking selection macro

Tags: vba, selection, locked

I want to create a macro to lock / unlock cells based on Locked range property, but I am having trouble firing the Case Null section of the statement( The first 2 work fine)

```
Sub Lockunlockselection()

Dim c As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
'Dim lck As String
'Dim unlck As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
'lck = Empty
'unlck = Empty

Set c = selection

Select Case c.Locked
Case False
c.Locked = True
msgbox "Selection " & c.Address & " is now locked!", vbInformation, Date
Case True
c.Locked = False
msgbox "Selection " & c.Address & " is now unlocked!", vbInformation, Date
Case Null ' this would be if mix of locked and unlocked
c.Locked = True
msgbox "Mix of locked and unlocked cells!" & vbLf & vbLf & "Cells are all now locked!", vbInformation + vbExclamation, "Info.."
End Select

End Sub
```

Why is this not firing??

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution (if anyone is interested):

```
Sub Lockunlockselection()

Dim c As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
'Dim lck As String
'Dim unlck As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
'lck = Empty
'unlck = Empty

Set c = selection

If IsNull(c.Locked) = True Then ' this would be if mix of locked and unlocked
msgbox "Mix of locked and unlocked cells!" & vbLf & vbLf & "Cells are all now locked!", vbExclamation + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Info.."
c.Locked = True
Else
    Select Case c.Locked
    Case False
    c.Locked = True
    msgbox "Selection " & c.Address & " is now locked!", vbInformation, Date
    Case True
    c.Locked = False
    msgbox "Selection " & c.Address & " is now unlocked!", vbInformation, Date
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```